# How do I stop Google sheets from displaying apostrophe in blank cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

After I export the result of Bigquery to Google sheets, Google sheets automatically puts an apostrophe in blank cells.
I noticed that the apostrophe are only present in the fields that are strings and not integer.
This screws up my reporting. Is there any way to remove this automatic apostrophes being displayed? Thank you.

**Solution :**
I know it's been a long time since I posted the question here but I have the solution to my problem. As CarlosE and Mateo Randwolf pointed out it's Google sheet that treats even integers/floating points as a string if they are not casted or safe casted to their respective datatype before exporting to a gsheet. So if your field is a integer then use cast( field_name as int64) in the query or replace cast with safe_case. it works too

Comment: An apostrophe (') in front of the number, will treat it as text. you need to write your data as values and not text

Comment: I belive that is happening because the format of your cells are Plain Text. Try the following, select the cells you are exporting -> format -> number. Let me know if this works, if it didn't we can try something else. For more info read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31752200)

Comment: Hello, I know it's been a long time since I posted the question here but I have the solution to my problem.
As CarlosE and Mateo Randwolf pointed out it's Google sheet that treats even integers/floating points as a string if they are not **casted** or **safe casted** to their respective datatype before exporting to a gsheet.
So if your field is a integer then use cast( field_name as int64) in the query or replace cast with safe_case. it works too.